# can some one explain this code to me

Tags: graphql

Good day im  newbie here and im tackling graphql and im having some problem on mutation can someone explain this block of code for me thank you

```
 RootMutation: {
createAuthor: (root, args) => { return Author.create(args); },
createPost: (root, { authorId, tags, title, text }) => {
  return Author.findOne({ where: { id: authorId } }).then( (author) => {
    console.log('found', author);
    return author.createPost( { tags: tags.join(','), title, text });
  });
},
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is an example of two mutations in a GraphQL server. We can break it down to understand what is going on.

First let's look at the type system. A GraphQL schema normally has two root fields `query` and `mutation` (and sometimes `subscription`). These root fields are the root of your data hierarchy and expose the queries (GET requests) and mutations (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc requests) that you have access to.

By the looks of it you are implementing a schema with a root mutation type that looks like this:

```
type Mutation {
  createAuthor: Author
  createPost: Post
}
```

A type in GraphQL is made up of a set of fields each of which can have an associated resolver. Resolvers in GraphQL are like the event handlers you would attach to endpoints in REST.

The code that you have above is defining two **resolvers** that will handle the logic associated with the `createAuthor` and `createPost` mutations. I.E. the code in the `createPost` resolver is what will be run when I issue a query like this:

```
mutation CreatePost($post: CreatePostInput!) {
  createPost(input: $post) {
    id
    title
    tags
    text
  }
}
```

The GraphQL runtime parses the query and routes the operation to the correct resolver depending on the content of the query. In this example, it would see that I am calling the `createPost` mutation and would make sure to call the `createPost` resolver which in your case looks like this:

```
createPost: (root, { authorId, tags, title, text }) => {
  return Author.findOne({ where: { id: authorId } }).then( (author) => {
    console.log('found', author);
    return author.createPost( { tags: tags.join(','), title, text });
  });
},
```

To understand how a resolver works, let's look at the **GraphQLFieldResovler** type definition from **graphql-js**

```
export type GraphQLFieldResolver<TSource, TContext> = (
  source: TSource,
  args: { [argName: string]: any },
  context: TContext,
  info: GraphQLResolveInfo
) => mixed;
```

As you can see a GraphQLFieldResolver is a function that takes 4 arguments.

1. **source**: The source is the parent object of the current field. For example if you were defining a resolver for a field `fullName` on the `User` type, the source would be the full user object.
2. **args**: The args are any input arguments for that resolver. In my query above it would contain the value of the `$post` variable.
3. **context**: Context is a global context for a GraphQL execution. This is useful for passing information around that a resolver might need. For example, you include a database connection that you can use from your resolvers without importing it in every file.
4. **info**: The info object contains information about your GraphQL schema, the query, and other information such as the path to the current resolver being executed. This is useful in many ways. Here is one post talking about how you can use it to precompute queries: (https://scaphold.io/community/blog/querying-relational-data-with-graphql/)

This idea of having types and field resolvers is part of what makes GraphQL so powerful. Once you've defined you type system and the resolvers for their fields you can structure your schema however you want and GraphQL will always make sure to call the correct resolver no matter how deeply nested a query might be.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for this even im still confuse it help me :D

Comment: @mparis Great explanation, but when will you explain me and answer about mine questions